# Can lodash debounce run at least once while it's being debounced?

Tags: react-native, lodash, debouncing

I am debouncing a method and wanted to know if it's possible to process it at least once while it's actively being debounced.

Example: The debounce wait is set to 1 second, and during 10 seconds straight, the function is being called actively (more often than 1 second, resulting in the function still not invoked yet). Could I at least run the function once say at the 5th second? So I do not have to wait till 10s fully pass before it runs finally once.

My fear is that if the process is "busy" and constantly bombarded by requests, I would still like to process something.

Not sure if it's relevant, but this is part of React Native.

Answer (score 0):

Debouncing partially blocks unnecessary requests but does not guarantee that new requests will not be dispatched while the system is busy.

We should implement a mechanism to detect if the system is busy or not then we decide to dispatch a new request.

```js
import debounce from "lodash/debounce";

function Component() {
  // Detect the status of an expensive operation
  let operationRunning = false;

  const runExpensiveOperation = () => {
    // If expensive operation still running, discard  dispatching
    // new operations
    if (operationRunning) {
      return;
    }

    operationRunning = true;

    /** Do expensive operations here - Writing, reading 
        from database or compress files,... **/

    operationRunning = false;
  };

  const debounceExpensiveOperation = debounce(runExpensiveOperation, 1000);

  // ássign debounced function for the event handler
}
```

Comment: @rockpowwer check new solution

Comment: in my scenario, I am not awaiting the operation and it isn't actually expensive. it's just displaying notifications to the user. But since server can send a lot of notifications in a short period of time, i'd rather rate limit them and skip a few and show max one notification say per 5s (with being ok to skip some since there is a place to see them anyway later). so what im trying to do is still show something to the user during 10s of active receiving from server...